# DateTimeParseException could not be parsed at index 16 Java Seldomly Triggered

Tags: java, datetime

recently I faced this problem. But this happen seldomly and sometime my program run smoothly. What is triggering this exception? How to completely solve this problem:

Code:

```
63: DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
64: String strLocalDate = loginRecords.getLoginDate().toLocalDateTime().toString();
65: LocalDateTime lastLogin = LocalDateTime.parse(strLocalDate, formatter);
```

Exception text:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-11-21T14:15' could not be parsed at index 16
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.fesca.view.MainMenuFrame.<init>(MainMenuFrame.java:65)
    at com.fesca.control.listener.CheckingRehabDateListener.run(CheckingRehabDateListener.java:287)
```

Comment: change your formater from yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm and then start parsing.

Comment: You're missing the seconds in your input time. Either add seconds, or as Usman said change your formatter.

Comment: @UsmanKurd I have second in my database. The problem occur when the second is 00. Other values seem working well. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Exception in thread "Thread-5"
>   java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-11-21T14:15' could
>   not be parsed at index 16

Change

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```

to

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm", Locale.US);
```

Since you are formatting upto minutes (`2015-11-21T14:15`) only not included seconds (`ss`)

or add the seconds part.

Comment: I have second in my database. The problem occur when the second is 00. Other values seem working well. Any solution?

Comment: If seconds in 00, use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. @SkyvrawleR

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting ss in your date string sometimes as seen in error producing date - `2015-11-21T14:15`. Use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

### You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter`

`java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format (e.g. `2015-11-21T14:15`).

### What's wrong with your pattern?

Your date-time string doesn't have seconds but you have used `ss`. Your pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` can be used after removing `:ss` from it.

**Demo**:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String strDateTime = "2015-11-21T14:15";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Parsing with your pattern after correction
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2015-11-21T14:15
2015-11-21T14:15
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.